# wget not working in annaconda jupyter notebook - Windows. Alternative?

Tags: python, windows, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, wget

I am trying to download github dataset from here:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heyunh2015/PARADE_dataset/main/PARADE_test.txt

using a windows machine, and the anaconda host to play jupyter notebook, I am trying to directly download it in the machine using the following command:

```
 !wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heyunh2015/PARADE_dataset/main/PARADE_test.txt
```

However, it is giving me the following error:

> 'wget' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
> program or batch file.

Then I tried again after the following command:

```
!pip install wget
```

still the same error.

Next, I tried `curl`, and the error went away, but I am unable to access my downloaded file either through code (the file doesn't exist) or using GUI (doesn't show up in the current working directory).

What to do?

Comment: You don't need an alternative. `!` isn't valid in the Windows shell. Just use `pip install wget`. If you really want a Linux environment on Windows use WSL2 with your distro fo choice. Visual Studio Code can even use it as its intepreter

Comment: But that gives an 'invalid syntax' error.

Comment: As for executing `wget` directly, that's not a shell command or Windows command-line tool. You'd have to install it first. The [GNU wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) tool can be installed either by downloading it directly or installing it through a package manager like Chocolatey or Winget, eg `choco install wget` or `winget install GnuWin32.Wget`

Comment: `that gives an 'invalid syntax' error` what did? Because `pip install wget` works just fine. I just run it. `!pip` would *never* work on Windows, a starting `!` is invalid syntax. `pip install wget` installs the Python package, not the tool itself so you still can't use `wget` from the command line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer.

```
import wget

url = "<source>"
wget.download(url, '<destination>')
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with what you asked. To use `import wget` you'd have to actually install wget which you claimed you couldn't. BTW `pip install wget` works  fine. That's a Python package though, not a command-line tool. There *are* tools named `wget` but you have to install them

Answer (score 0):

> wget not working in annaconda jupyter notebook - Windows. Alternative?

`python`'s standard library has function for downloading files, called [`urlretrieve`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlretrieve) inside `urllib.request`. Simple usage example

```
import urllib.request
urllib.request.urlretrieve("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heyunh2015/PARADE_dataset/main/PARADE_test.txt","PARADE_test.txt")
```

Explanation: 2 arguments are provided, URL and filename. Note that in this form this does not report progress. You need to wait until it finishes. If you must have see linked docs for discussion of 3rd argument to `urllib.request.urlretrieve`

Answer (score 0):

First, install wget:

```
pip install wget
```

Followed by

```
import wget
url = <url>  # in brackets
filename = wget.download(url)
```